# Why is this last line of code necessary?

Tags: javascript

I understand all of the following code from an example on a book I'm reading. Except the commented line. I'm thinking that without it the loop never ends? I don't understand the logic behind it though.

```
var drink = "Energy drink";
var lyrics = "";
var cans = "99";

while (cans > 0) {
    lyrics = lyrics + cans + " cans of " + drink + " on the wall <br>";
    lyrics = lyrics + cans + " cans of " + drink + " on the wall <br>";
    lyrics = lyrics + "Take one down, pass it around, <br>";

    if (cans > 1) {
        lyrics = lyrics + (cans-1) + " cans of" + drink + " on the wall  <br>";
    }
    else {
        lyrics = lyrics + "No more cans of" + drink + " on the wall<br>";
    }
    cans = cans - 1;  // <-- This line I don't understand
}

document.write(lyrics);
```

Comment: Do you have any experience in programming before? This might help you http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptwhile.php

Comment: @dpp html/css I'm trying to learn my way into html5 which of course requires javascript. Thanks for all the help guys. I don't wanna pass any exercise of the book I'm reading without been 100% sure of understanding it.

Comment: You can get rid of that line if you initialise cans to 100 `var cans = 100` then change the condition to `while (cans--)`

Comment: @RobG, for christ's sake, the OP is having difficulty with some very simple syntax and you suggest that he uses something that will surely look way more cryptic?? Wow.

Comment: The OP is learning and has good answers. In a week or so s/he'll be wondering why it wasn't written that way from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a loop that starts at 99 (`var cans = "99"`) then counts backwards to 0. The highlighted line is the line that says "subtract one". If it weren't for that line, it would keep looping and adding `99 cans of Energy drink on the wall` forever.

BTW, `document.write` is just *bad*, and `var cans = "99"` should be `var cans = 99`. Of course, this probably isn't your code, just sayin'. My advice: keep reading.

Comment: Why does it need to subtract one?

Comment: to count down to zero as he says

Answer (score 0):

Like D Strout said, it's a loop.  Basically your code is saying "while the variable *cans* is greater than 0 then do this action".  If the value of cans never changes then it would fail or repeat indefinitely.
So basically you are starting with 99 cans.  For each can it is subtracting the number of cans by 1 until it is 0, at which point the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

D. Strout is right...

But just an FYI - since you are learning - you can also do the exact same thing with a '`for`' loop instead of the '`while`' loop.

Like this:

```
// store the div in a variable to use later - at the bottom 
var beer_holder = document.getElementById("beer_holder");

// Non-alcoholic to keep it PG
var drink = "O'Doul's";

var lyrics = "";

var cans = "99";

// Create a variable called 'i' and set it to the cans variable amount. 
// Check if i is greater than 0,
// if it is, than do what is between the curly brackets, then subtract 1 from cans
for(var i=cans; i > 0; i--){

    lyrics = i + " cans of " + drink + " on the wall, " + i + " cans of " + drink +
        " take one down, pour it down the sink, " + (i - 1) + " cans of O'Doul's on the wall."

    // take the paragraph tag and put the lyrics within it
    //  the <br/> tags make sure each lyric goes on a seperate line
    beer_holder.innerHTML += lyrics + "<br/><br/>";

}
```

Here is a link to a working example if you want to play around with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/CHyh2/

​